# How can I use the arguments passed with pushNamed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

Say I have two routes **/firstRoute** and **/secondRoute**, both for the widgets **FirstRoute** and **SecondRoute** respectively. I'm pushing a named route onto the stack with some arguments, like so...

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    "/secondRoute",
    arguments: <String, String>{"key" : "value"},
)
```

How can I now use this value in the **SecondRoute**? 
Looked at the docs but it doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create class for arguments:

```
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

And extract them inside widget:

```
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings and cast
    // them as ScreenArguments.
    final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And for sending params:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
  arguments: ScreenArguments(
    'Extract Arguments Screen',
    'This message is extracted in the build method.',
  ),
);
```

Comment: In the context of the question, what is firstRoute and secondRoute here?

Comment: In your case use "/secondRoute" instead of `ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName` and send arguments to it. It's just an example how you can send and extract needed arguments

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, been stuck on this for days :D

Comment: i was try it. but, it give error 'the getter 'settings' was called on null' in ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments. what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 8):

Use `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments`

Inside your build method of the `/secondRoute`:

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
final arg1 = args["key"];
```